# Validator.ValidateObject with "validateAllProperties" to true stop at first error

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0

I have a custom class (to be simple) :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyClass {
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set;}
}
```

I want to validate this object, and get an exception with everything not correct.

If I do :

```
void Validate() {
    var objectToValidate = new MyClass { }; // Both properties are null at this time
    var ctx = new ValidationContext(objectToValidate, null, null);
    Validator.ValidateObject(objectToValidate, ctx, true);
}
```

A ValidationException is thrown but it shows only the first error, even I specify true to the `validateAllProperties` parameter.

if I refactor a bit my code :

```
void Validate() {
    var objectToValidate = new MyClass { }; // Both properties are null at this time
    var ctx = new ValidationContext(objectToValidate, null, null);
    var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(objectToValidate, ctx, errors, true);

    if(!isValid) {
        throw new AggregateException(
            errors.Select((e)=>new ValidationException(e.ErrorMessage)
        );
    }
}
```

I can actually have all my errors.

Why does the first code snippet works as expected ? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the code. The ValidationErrors class should be ValidationResult.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Validator.ValidateObject** goes through all validation attributes and throws **ValidationException** for the first one that fails. I don't think one can get the list of all properties that failed this way.

The MSDN documentation is a bit confusing here, it says:

> The ValidateObject method **evaluates each ValidationAttribute attribute** that is associated with the object type. If validateAllProperties is set to true, the method validates **the property values** of the object.

TryValidateObject method manual continues:

> It also checks whether each property that is marked with RequiredAttribute is provided.

I confirm that it always checks all the Required attributes, regardless of validateAllProperties. But if you have, for example, a Range validation attribute it will only check it when validateAllProperties is true (because this is when it **validates the property value**). A bit confusing, but as you noticed, **TryValidateObject** shows all the failed properties and this is what I'm using for my project as well.

Comment: thanks for your explanations... it's actually confusing and the parameter name is not explicit. I'll keep my aggregate exception... it's not a big issue for me:)

Comment: Evgenii is correct. You cannot get a list of all invalid properties through ``Validator.ValidateObject``. It merely returns the first failed. See the source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/60a4f8b853f60a424e36c7bf60f9b5b5f1973ed1/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/Validator.cs#L188)

Comment: Just for future readers, in newer versions of DataAnnotations there's an overload for `Validator.TryValidateObject` which accepts an `ICollection<ValidationResult>`, and if any provided, it will validate every property and gather all the errors into that collection for us.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási You have to explicitly ask for `validateAllObject: true` otherwise the properties will not be validated.